Formula to return header data for group of columns where sum is greater than 0
I have a Google Sheet where the following data is on the Operator Qty tab (it continues indefinitely horizontally and vertically in this fashion):



OPERATOR:
Sam L




Bob R




Sandra S




Tom E




Becky W








SHIFT:
Weekend




Day




Night




Day




Day






DATE
CH
LD
RQ
AQ
PQ
CH
LD
RQ
AQ
PQ
CH
LD
RQ
AQ
PQ
CH
LD
RQ
AQ
PQ
CH
LD
RQ
AQ
PQ


Apr 30, 2023
2
96
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


May 1, 2023
0
0
0
0
0
5
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


May 2, 2023
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
155
0


May 9, 2023
0
0
0
0
0
0
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


May 11, 2023
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
122
0
0
0
0
0


Jun 15, 2023
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0



On the Dashboard tab, I am displaying a month and year in cell A1 ('May 2023' in this case) which is being calculated by this formula: =TEXT(EDATE(today(),-11),"MMM YYY")
Using this month and year to narrow down which rows to search for using the dates in column A on the Operator Qty tab, I am trying to create a formula for cell A2 of the Dashboard tab which will list all the operators in range A2:A12 who appear in row 1 of the Operator Sheet and meet these conditions:

They are on the Day shift (as specified in row 2).
They have a number in any one of the cells in the five columns assigned to them which is greater than 0 (so Bob R's range is G5:K8).

So as per my example above, this should be my output:



May 2023




Bob R


Tom E


Becky W
























However, the best I have been able to do is to use the following formula, but it only returns the operator name who has a number in the applicable range larger than 0 in the column directly under the name in row 1: =FLATTEN(FILTER('Operator Qty'!$B$1:$1,('Operator Qty'!$B$2:$2="Day")*TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(('Operator Qty'!$A$4:$A>=EOMONTH(C$1,-1)+1)*('Operator Qty'!$A$4:$A<=EOMONTH(C$1,0))*('Operator Qty'!$B$4:$9>0)),SEQUENCE(ROWS('Operator Qty'!$A$4:$A),1,1,0))>0)))
How would I search all groups of 5 columns and display the name of the first column header of each group?

Can you share a minimal reproducible sample of your dataset.  As your expected result involved more tabs as per your posted question. This way the community will have better oversight on your project.

Absolutely! The last time I did that I was recommend the use of tables, but I can see how that could get confusing in this case. Please see a sample sheet here.


You may try:
=let(Σ,reduce(,'Operator Qty'!B4:index('Operator Qty'!Z:Z,match(,0/('Operator Qty'!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(〱,lambda(x,scan(,x,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))),hstack(index('Operator Qty'!A:A,row(c)),index(〱('Operator Qty'!1:1),column(c)),index(〱('Operator Qty'!2:2),column(c)),c))))),
     unique(ifna(filter(index(Σ,,2),eomonth(A1,)=eomonth(index(Σ,,1),),index(Σ,,3)="Day",index(Σ,,4)),"-_-")))


Updated formula:
=let(Σ,index(match(,0/('Operator Qty'!A4:A<>""))),Λ,tocol(,1),Ξ,reduce(Λ,'Operator Qty'!B1:1,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(c="",Λ,hstack(tocol(map(indirect("'Operator Qty'!A4:A"&Σ),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,5,Σ)))),wrapcols(c,Σ*5,c),wrapcols(offset(c,1,),Σ*5,offset(c,1,)),tocol(offset(c,3,,Σ,5))))))),
     unique(ifna(filter(index(Ξ,,2),eomonth(A1,)=eomonth(index(Ξ,,1),),index(Ξ,,3)="Day",index(Ξ,,4)),"-_-")))


This is providing results! What would you recommend if I wanted the operator names on the Dashboard to appear from top to bottom in A2:A11 as they apply in order from left to right on the Operator Qty tab? Currently they change order based on which cell in each of their 5 columns is larger than 0. Also, is there an efficient way to automatically identify the last column on the Operator Qty sheet if this is ever changed?

One more thing I noticed - when trying to incorporate this into my main sheet, I quickly get this error: 'Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula.' Do you have any thoughts on how we might avoid this?

Recreate the scenario in the test sheet & I can test it out.

Showcase you expected output as well (manually)

The expected output has been added to column B of the Dashboard tab.

Try the updated formula added to the answer

That seems to be doing the trick, thank you! Sadly it seems to be causing major slowdowns/crashes on my main sheet which has much more data on the Operator Qty sheet (I updated my example to demonstrate this, when data is added to the Operator Qty sheet it takes a long time to process). Is there a way to ease the load by perhaps minimizing the amount of data this formula is processing so it is only considering the rows that fall within the month specified, as opposed to the entire range of data?

Hopefully someone else will pitch in with an alternative solution.

I will mark your solution as solved since it does accomplish what I requested. If you get a chance to take another look at my example sheet, you will find v2 tabs which use helper columns and it works better with this formula: =IFERROR(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(FILTER('Operator Qty v2'!$B$3:$3,('Operator Qty v2'!$B$4:$4="Day")*TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(('Operator Qty v2'!$A$6:$A>=EOMONTH(A$1,-1)+1)*('Operator Qty v2'!$A$6:$A<=EOMONTH(A$1,0))*('Operator Qty v2'!$B$6:$1569>0)),SEQUENCE(ROWS('Operator Qty v2'!$A$6:$A),1,1,0))>0))))) ...but I would like to know if this could be made even more efficient.
